# If something is left out from the final version of a movie or anything else, how do you describe it?

Tags: word-request, synonyms

If some piece of a movie script or videogame content is left out, not included in the final cut/version, what attribute could one use? 'Discarded' or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd usually say it was simply *cut*, or that it's *cut content* (more so in videogames), or a *deleted scene* (in movies).

*Left on the cutting room floor* is a more poetic way to refer to deleted scenes or content.

Comment: 'Withheld'? 3 more to go...

Answer (score 1):

If it was left out and only ever appeared in the script or the outline, just say it was left out.  For something to be *cut*, however, it must first appear somewhere where it can be cut.

If it was included in the creating of the game/movie and then removed during final production the correct term is **edited out**.

> The scene where they fell into the quicksand was **edited out**.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the context, one of the following might suffice-

1. Deleted - simply removed
2. Censored - removed because of sensitive content
3. Discarded - more suitable for cases where
   something is not good enough,
   synonymous with rejected
4. Eliminate - similar to deleted

Comment: Do you think 'discarded' is good?

Comment: I don’t see why not. It pretty much implies the same thing as removing something because of lack of need, or quality. Feel free to correct me, though.

Comment: 'Expurgate' doesn't seem to fit: https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/expurgate. The object there is not what is removed but, rather, something something else was removed from

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev I got your point. Thanks for the suggestion.